# Change another activity without open it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is it possible to add a `textView` on Activity B without showing it?

What I mean is, when i press a button (on `DiallerActivity`), then a `textView` will be added on `HistoryActivity` without leaving `DiallerActivity`.

How can I do this?

Comment: In almost all cases, only one of your activities will be running at a time so really you want to ask how you would update the `HistoryActivity` *when it resumes* based on a change made in `DialerActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to a add textView on Activity B without show it ?

No, not directly.

An `Activity` is a special case Android class and shouldn't be treated as a normal Java class. Effectively the purpose of an `Activity` is to act as a framework for a UI so, if an `Activity` isn't visible then there basically is no UI. In other words, how can something be a user-interface if the user isn't able to see or interact with it?

As logical Chimp suggests, the changes should be with respect to some form of data history (a database or `SharedPreferences`) and it is the responsibility of your `HistoryActivity` to update its visual elements (`TextViews`) next time it is started.

One `Activity` shouldn't try to modify the look, feel or behaviour of another `Activity` except indirectly by changing some form of global data or state or by passing data to it if the first `Activity` is responsible for starting the second.

Comment: just to add on to this, if you do attempt to access Views of an Activity that is not visible, you will get a NullPointerException a lot of the time.  do not try to access Views within an Activity that is not in the foreground.

Comment: @moonlightcheese : Agreed. That's basically what I was aiming to say in the last paragraph but probably didn't word it clearly. An `Activity` is a self-contained entity and attempts to directly access / modify an `Activity` from any other application component will either fail (as you say) or may have unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm - not sure I fully understand your question.  Are you wanting to append the dialled number to the 'HistoryActivity' without showing it?

If so, I suggest you separate your data (list of dialled numbers) from the view (HistoryActivity).  Then, you only have to add the dialled number to the data record used to hold them (suggest a list).  When the user opens the HistoryActivity, then you can just draw as many text fields as required to display the data.

Comment: Yes, That's Exactly What I Mean.